# Table is not created as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a table to represent data extracted from firebase RT database, I have the following data in json format:

```
var jsonData =
            {
                availability: {
                    supermarket01: {
                        '2342342': {
                            green100: 'no',
                            green200: 'yes',
                            red200: 'yes',
                            yellow: 'no',
                            purple100: 'yes',
                            cyan100: 'no'
                        },
                        '58943792': {
                            green200: 'yes',
                            orange200: 'yes',
                            red200: 'no'
                        },
                        '398489593': {
                            green200: 'no',
                            orange200: 'no',
                            red200: 'yes'
                        },
                        '1605290957000': {
                            orange: 'yes',
                            green2123: 'no',
                            green222: 'yes'
                        }
                    },
                    supermarket02: {
                        '23423423': {
                            green200: 'yes',
                            orange200: 'no',
                            red200: 'no'
                        },
                        '23947928': {
                            green200: 'yes',
                            orange200: 'no',
                            red200: 'yes'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to create a table which looks somehing like the photo below:

[image: table]

but I'm getting a table which looks like this:

[image: table01]

what I've tried so far:

```
function jsonTabulizer(jsonData, selector) {
    var reportType = [],
        storeKeys = [],
        reportKeys = [],
        productKeys = [],
        table = document.createElement("table"),
        row = table.insertRow();
    reportType = Object.keys(jsonData);
    storeKeys = Object.keys(jsonData[reportType]);
    for (j = 0; j < storeKeys.length; j++) {
        reportKeys[j] = Object.keys(jsonData[reportType][storeKeys[j]]);
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = storeKeys[j];
        console.log(reportKeys[j].length);
        cell.setAttribute("rowSpan", reportKeys[j].length);
        for (k = 0; k < reportKeys[j].length; k++) {
            productKeys[j] = Object.keys(jsonData[reportType][storeKeys[j]][reportKeys[j][k]]);
            row = table.insertRow();
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.innerHTML = reportKeys[j][k];
            // console.log(productKeys[j]);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("test_table").appendChild(table);
}
```

and in html body:

```
<div id="test_table"></div>
```

can anyone help me to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new row in each iteration so your `row = table.insertRow();` line is outside first loop it should be inside .Then , first `td` in every `tr` will have total rowspan depending on `keys length` so you need to add get total length and set rowspan of first `td` same for other `trs`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var jsonData = {
  availability: {
    supermarket01: {
      '2342342': {
        green100: 'no',
        green200: 'yes',
        red200: 'yes',
        yellow: 'no',
        purple100: 'yes',
        cyan100: 'no'
      },
      '58943792': {
        green200: 'yes',
        orange200: 'yes',
        red200: 'no'
      },
      '398489593': {
        green200: 'no',
        orange200: 'no',
        red200: 'yes'
      },
      '1605290957000': {
        orange: 'yes',
        green2123: 'no',
        green222: 'yes'
      }
    },
    supermarket02: {
      '23423423': {
        green200: 'yes',
        orange200: 'no',
        red200: 'no'
      },
      '23947928': {
        green200: 'yes',
        orange200: 'no',
        red200: 'yes'
      }
    }
  }
}
jsonTabulizer(jsonData)

function jsonTabulizer(jsonData, selector) {
  var reportType = [],
    storeKeys = [],
    reportKeys = [],
    productKeys = [],
    table = document.createElement("table"),

    reportType = Object.keys(jsonData);
  storeKeys = Object.keys(jsonData[reportType]);
  for (j = 0; j < storeKeys.length; j++) {
    var rowspan = 0; //decalre this
    reportKeys[j] = Object.keys(jsonData[reportType][storeKeys[j]]);

    var row = table.insertRow(); //put this line inside
    var cell1 = row.insertCell();
    cell1.innerHTML = storeKeys[j];
    rowspan += reportKeys[j].length //outer array length

    for (k = 0; k < reportKeys[j].length; k++) {
      productKeys[j] = Object.keys(jsonData[reportType][storeKeys[j]][reportKeys[j][k]]);
      rowspan += productKeys[j].length
      var row = table.insertRow();
      cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.innerHTML = reportKeys[j][k];
      cell.setAttribute("rowspan", parseInt(productKeys[j].length + 1)); //add rowspan 
      for (m = 0; m < productKeys[j].length; m++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = productKeys[j][m]; //(yellow, red ..key)
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = jsonData[reportType][storeKeys[j]][reportKeys[j][k]][productKeys[j][m]]; //value (yes,no..)

      }

    }
    cell1.setAttribute("rowspan", parseInt(rowspan + 1)); //add rowspan to first tds 
  }
  document.getElementById("test_table").appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test_table"></div>
```